# Is this pantry wall load bearing?

Tags: structural, load-bearing

I would like to remove the wall in my kitchen. It is a pantry closet, which I'd like to replace with cabinets. We didn't think it was a load-bearing wall since is only about 2 feet by 30 inches but when removing the drywall it seems to be reinforced with extra wood. I got the blueprints but still not sure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unlikely that the wall is load bearing for the following reasons. However, no one looking through the internet can be certain.

- The header isn't sized for loads
- There's no header specified in the plan as there is at obviously load-bearing locations
- The wall is very short
- The wall is near the building exterior
- Your home appears modern enough that it would have full-span trusses or floor joists

Since you have the drawings, turn to the roof framing/truss diagram. If all the common trusses in that kitchen are the same, there's your huckleberry.

Comment: To add to this, the pantry walls are also extremely close to the actual walls and very short. They wouldn't add much regarding load bearing capacity, nor stabillty, that the main walls don't already provide.

Comment: Thanks so much, guys I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.